# VBA to Copy Information From a Folder of Files and Compile Information to a Single Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, paste

I am trying to get a range of data from multiple workbooks in a single folder location, and past all that information into a single worksheet on a pre-existing file.

So far, I have the function to get the list of files:

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant

Dim FileArray() As Variant
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

FileCount = 0
FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

Do While FileName <> ""
    FileCount = FileCount + 1
    ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
    FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
GetFileList = FileArray
Exit Function

NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function

Sub ClearCosting()

Dim var As Variant
Dim loc As String
loc = "C:\Users\m.raby\Desktop\testfolder"
var = GetFileList(loc & "*.xls*")

Dim StrFile As Variant
For Each StrFile In var

    Workbooks.Open (loc & StrFile)

        sh.Activate
        On Error Resume Next
        Set uCost = Cells.Find(What:="Run rate", After:=[A1], LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Range(Cells(uCost.Row + 1, uCost.Column - 4), Cells(uCost.Row.End(xlDown), uCost.Column + 8)).Copy
        On Error GoTo 0

Next StrFile

End Sub
```

What I am stuck on now is the retrieval of the data. I am trying to get the information located one cell below and four to the left of the text "Run rate", and copy from that cell, to the last cell before a blank cell (in the row), and eight columns to the right.

I want to copy this information, and paste it as is into a workbook located on my desktop, named "sampletest.xlsx", along with the filename that it came from in each row of information. After this is done for the FIRST sheet only (should be the active sheet in all the workbooks), I want this to go onto the next workbook, and append the similar information in the next ow on "sampletest.xlsx"

How can I capture both this range for only the very first worksheet and then capture the filename, and append all this information to the single workbook, while looping through a folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the full code, but it should help you.

When you work with multiple workbooks keep track of them. For example start with:

```
Dim CurrWB As Workbook
Set CurrWB = ActiveWorkbook
```

Then in the cycle:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
For Each StrFile In var
  Set WB = Workbooks.Open(loc & StrFile)
  ...
  WB.Close
Next StrFile
```

Inside the cycle you can find the area to copy doing something like:

```
R1 = 1
Do While WB.Sheets("Sheet name").Cells(R, 2) <> "Starting text"
  R1 = R1 + 1
Loop

R2 = R1 + 1
Do While WB.Sheets("Sheet name").Cells(R2, 2) <> "Ending text"
  R = R + 1
Loop

For R = R1 to R2
  CurrWB.Sheets("Report").Cells(RReport, 3) = WB.Sheets("Report").Cells(R, 3)
  RReport = RReport + 1
Next R
```

Comment: I don't have any problem with looping it throughout the workbooks, it is more of a difficulty with the actual coding for the copy + paste

Comment: I added two cycles to the post. Now it shows how to find the start and end rows in the file just opened, and how to copy data between the two rows to the original sheet. There are better ways to do that, but in my opinion this is the best way to understand what's going on.